# I don't get anything when calling circuit.draw()

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm following the YouTube tutorials for Programming on Quantum Computers and I've completed everything until I reach `circuit.draw()` since I don't get $|0\rangle$ or 0 next to `q` or `c`. Here's my code:

```
from qiskit import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)

%matplotlib inline

circuit.draw()

[
q0_0:
q0_1:
c0: 2/
]
```

and so when I attempt an H gate, I receive the error  `'QuantumRegister' object is not callable`:

```
circuit.h(qr(0))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-c8b4318b743b> in <module>
----> 1 circuit.h(qr(0))

TypeError: 'QuantumRegister' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a change on the default arguments of `draw()` function. To reproduce the same visualization as on the youtube video, try:

```
circuit.draw(initial_state=True, 
             cregbundle=False)
```

and add a Hadamard gate like:

```
circuit.h(qr[0])
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Where can I see other changes as to avoid problems like this in the future?

Comment: Qiskit Documentation is the place. For example, https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.draw.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.draw

Answer (score 2):

The following also work for me if it is interest to you:

```
from qiskit import *
%matplotlib inline

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.draw()
```

[image]